# Test onChange event, values fail to match regardless of the approach

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I've been trying to test input onChange event using jest and enzyme and match the values but regardless of what I do I get failed test. here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import InputField from './InputField';

describe('InputField component', () => {

   let wrapped;
   let mockFunc;

   beforeEach(()=> {

     mockFunc = jest.fn();

        const props = {
            name: 'email',
            value: 'mytestemail@gmail.com',
            handleChange: mockFunc
        };

        wrapped = mount(<InputField {...props}/>)

    });

    it('should trigger onChange test 1', () => {

        wrapped.find('input').simulate('change', {
            target: { value: 'test 1'}
        });

        wrapped.update();

        expect(wrapped.find('input').props().value).toEqual('test 1')

    }

    it('should trigger onChange test 2', () => {

        wrapped.find('input').prop('onChange', { 
            target: { value: 'test 2' }
        }); 

        wrapped.update();

        expect(wrapped.find('input').props().value).toEqual('test 2')

    });

    it('should trigger onChange test 3', () => {

        const event = {
            target: { value: 'test 3'}
        };

        wrapped.find('input').simulate('change', event);

        expect(mockFunc).toBeCalledWith('test 3');

    });

};
```

all of the above tests fail and cant match values regardless of what I do. handleChange function attached to the input field updates values via hooks. what I have been doing wrong and should I take some other approach to unit test input fields ?

Comment: Is this a reduced down example or are you really testing a HTML input element?

Comment: @DrewReese yes I am really unit testing input field. is my approach bad ?

Comment: @wentjun ok I want to understand what's the best approach, what should I be testing ?